# ACF repeater upcoming and past events

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building an Events page with Advanced Custom Fields + Repeater add-on in WordPress. It works. See the core code below. Apart from the compare date line everything else is identical between upcoming and past sections, and there are many lines of code in the actual case.

The question: Is there a way to simplify the code, perhaps merge the two parts into one? And keep the upcoming and past events in different blocks.

```
<?php
if (have_rows('events')) :
    while (have_rows('events')) : the_row();
        if ($date_posted >= $date_current) : // compare date
            // upcoming events...
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif;

if (have_rows('events')) :
    while (have_rows('events')) : the_row(); // compare date
        if ($date_posted < $date_current) :
            // past events...
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have is the simplest way to go, but here is another option (although a little more verbose).

```
$upcoming = [];
$past = [];

if ( have_rows( 'events' ) ) :
    while ( have_rows( 'events' ) ) : the_row();
        if ( $date_posted >= $date_current ) : // compare date
            $upcoming[] = // upcoming events markup
        elseif ( $date_posted < $date_current ) :
            $past[] = // past events markup
        endif;
    endwhile:
endif;
```

Then output the arrays in separate blocks with `foreach`;

```
foreach( $upcoming as $u_event ) :
   echo $u_event;
endforeach;
```

As I said, a little more code, but might be better for you if your goal is to combine the events into a single `while`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare date, then you need to convert date value into the string by using `strtotime()` function and compare those values. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
For Example:

```
<?php
if (have_rows('events')) :
    while (have_rows('events')) : the_row();
        $date_posted = get_sub_field('your_date_field_name'); 
        $date_posted = strtotime($date_posted); 
        $date_current = date('Ymd'); // the date format should be same as the date format on $date_posted
        $date_current = strtotime($date_current);
        if ($date_posted >= $date_current) : // compare date
            // upcoming events...
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif;

if (have_rows('events')) :
    while (have_rows('events')) : the_row(); // compare date
        $date_posted = get_sub_field('your_date_field_name'); 
        $date_posted = strtotime($date_posted); 
        $date_current = date('Ymd'); // the date format should be same as the date format on $date_posted
        $date_current = strtotime($date_current);
        if ($date_posted < $date_current) :
            // past events...
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: I have $date... stuff works already, the example in the question is simplified. your code won't work as I need upcoming and past in different blocks.

Comment: I have edited my answer. can you please check again?